# VBA Loop - I want my application the find first variable "After Upd" then stop looping. I am tying to end my loop once the first condition is met

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

```
Sub Search_Range_For_Text()
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In Range("b1:b100")
        If InStr(1, cell.Value, "After Upd") > 0 Then
            cell.Offset(0, 0).Value = "TH Value"

            MsgBox "verify if there was a check shot"
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: `offset(0,0)` ??

Comment: Don't use any loop but `Range.Find` and look at `xlPart`. Loops through `Range` objects slow down your code. And if you want to `Exit` your loop upon the first found value, then there is no use at all nomore =)

Answer (score 2):

Adding `Exit For` in the required place would allow you to exit the for loop.

```
Sub Search_Range_For_Text() Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Range("b1:b100")
    If InStr(1, cell.Value, "After Upd") > 0 Then
        cell.Value = "TH Value"
        MsgBox "verify if there was a check shot"
        Exit For
  End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

You may also use Do Until / Do While Loop instead of For Loop.

When you are not going to offset to left/right/up/down then you can simply use

> cell.Value = "TH Value"

instead of

> cell.Offset(0, 0).Value = "TH Value"

I hope it helps.

Comment: What if I want to delete all variables above the TH Value? How would I could I code that.

Comment: You need to explain little further. What do you mean by variables here ? are you referring to the cells above TH Value in range("b1:b100")?

Comment: It's a new question